# Caching mails on a server for outlook

Tags: email, caching, outlook

So I have a strange question here, maybe it's impossible but I hope some people are able to guide me on how to do this.

Me and my parents are running a business and are getting over 50 mails a day on 3 different mail boxes, and on a desktop this is fine but they are using tablets too to read these but the problem is that there isn't enough space to save all those mails offline.
So when they need some information from a client they need to go to the online mail panel and search there, but the searching is easier on Outlook than on Roundcube.

Is there a way to setup a local server that will stock all the mails, and when we search for a mail he temporary gets that mail from the server and deletes it after a few minutes from the tablet?

Comment: Firstly, thsi is not a programming question, so it belong on SuperUser, not on SO. Secondly, you can set Outlook (the desktop version) to cache all messages, not just X number of months - see the setting in your Exchange account settings. In the moble version of Outlook ,it is not configurable.

Comment: I'll post that on SuperUser then. Then problem is that there isn't enough space on the tablets for the mails, I'm talking multiple terrabytes here